# SSRS 2008: How to do multiple values report?

Tags: report, ssrs-2008

Right now I have an application which uses Reporting Services to render reports.
This is working nicely, I call each report with a given value (e.g. a ClientId), and the report gets rendered correctly.

However, what I'd like to do now is being able to send multiple ClientIDs to the report, and would like to get 1 pdf file with count(ClientsIDs) pages, each containing the report, according to the ClienID.

How is that possible?  I don't really know how to name what I want to do, so I don't really find answers on the net right now.  Maybe someone has a tutorial for me?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's a while since I've used Reporting Services but I think that you could do this quite straightforwardly by creating a new report and making your existing client specific report a sub report of that. I forget the precise details of how you would get it to repeat for each client though!

Comment: Thanks too Martin, for putting me on the right tracks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for are multi-value parameters.  You could create a new "main" report that contains a multi-value param to accept your client IDs.  Then use a subreport as Martin already mentioned to generate your current report for each client ID.

Here's the MS page on multi-value params: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292.aspx

And I wrote an article about using them with a stored proc: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/11/21/reporting-on-data-from-stored-procedures-part-2/
Even though in your case you may not be using SPs, it should help you to understand how these params work.

Comment: You save my day ! :-)
This is exactly what I wanted to do (and you are right, I don't use stored proc, but the process is quite the same).
Just for the records, I had to place my subreport in a list component, and specify the dataset which must be used.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out.  It does indeed make sense that you needed a list to repeat the subreport, well done :-)